# Why we use the key=get for sorting, how did work key method

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, methods

count={'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1}
s2 = sorted(sorted(count), key=count.get, reverse=True)
print(s2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the key argument to sorted work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483078/how-does-the-key-argument-to-sorted-work)

Comment: no this is not simmiliar.  i want to know how working the key=get . i can't understand here. what mean key=get

Comment: As the answer to that question explains, the `key` expects a function or method, and `dict.key` is a method while calling the method would pass the return value to the function, which isn't what it wants.

Comment: why we use dict.get, How it work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, `dict.get` gets the value specified from the dictionary.

Comment: what value the dict.get gets?

Comment: i can't go to automatically chat because my reputation is very low. when i click the link then show error.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted(count)` returns a sorted list of all the keys in the `count` dictionary.  So the `key` function will be called with each of those keys.

`count.get(k)` will return the value associated with the dictionary key `k`.  So the sort will be based on the **value** associated with that key string.  Since the key `'b'` has the largest value `3` and the sort is reversed, it will come first.

Comment: Thank you so much.. for explaining my problem statement.